# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when i config my subdomains

Tags: multisite, wp-config, subdomains, options

I use multisite like this

```
144.1.1.3 and 144.1.1.3/another_site
```

I need to use two subdomains like this

```
mysubdomain.mysite.com.br for 144.1.1.3
```

and

```
mysubdomain2.mysite.com.br for 144.1.1.3/another_site
```

I changed wp_options and when i'll try to access has the message:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
```

I need to do some configuration?